# Number of bits for physical address and virtual address

Tags: virtual-memory

According to my understanding a 32-bit machine determines the number of bits of physical address as 32 bits , and hence , we can address a physical memory space of 4GB. So the number of bits of physical address depends on the machine type . My question is what about the virtual address ? I mean what is used in a machine to determine the number of bits of a virtual address ? In paging for example , the number of bits for a virtual address is not necessarily the same as that of physical address. So what determines the number of bits of virtual address in a system ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases?redirectedfrom=MSDN I think this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A 32 bit machine usually has 2^32 bytes of address space *per process*. So the total address space can be much larger. An old PowerPC processor had a total of 2^52 bytes of address space, which just means it could handle one million processes. On the other hand, RAM can also be larger, for example there were 32 bit Intel processors that could address 64 GB of RAM. You would need at least 16 processes to use that RAM.

Comment: To add to this, you can simply print the address of a variable in C(or any other language), which would give you an idea about the no. of bits in logical address. These limits are decided by the operating system and may be influenced by the hardware.